# xamarin form: text binding enum status converter issue

Tags: wpf, xamarin, converters

I create a button, its content binding a status, I initialize the status, but the button content can't display corresponding text, in debug mode, I found it seems execute into a loop, after get the status, execute Convert function, then directly skip to the ConvertBack(), and back to Convert() again.

my code in xaml file is :

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding players}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" > 
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                       <Grid>                                                            
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                                                                                              
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                 ...                                                                                                                                                                                 
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToTextConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                           <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToTextExConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                           ...
                       </Grid>
                   </ViewCell>
             </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

and my converter is:

```
public class StatusToTextConverter: IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var status = (EStatus)value;

        if (status == EStatus.YES)
        {            
            return "V";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        var text = (string)value;
        if (text == "V")
            return EStatus.YES;
        else
            return EStatus.NO;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the binding mode of TwoWay that is causing the loop.

You need a way to break it.

In the view model property that it is bound to, check if the new value is the same as the old one and only set property changed if different.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I change the TwoWay mode, and use other workaround, it works now.

Comment: Please also mark one response here as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the implementation from Convert Back